# TypeError: throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'); Issue

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, issue-tracking

I am recieving this message even though I added intents to my Index.js

Discord.js version: 13.3.1
Node: 16.6.1

Code of my Index.js

```
const config = require('../config.json');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const { Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Bot is online!\n${bot.users.size} users, in ${bot.guilds.size} servers connected.`);
});
// HERE IS MONGODB BUT NOT SHOWING
const Client = require('./Structures/Client');
const WelcomeSchema = require(`../src/Models/welcome`)
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", async  (member, guil) => {
    WelcomeSchema.findOne({ guildId: member.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
        if(!data) return;
        const user = member.user;
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(data.channelId);
        channel.send({embed: {color: "BLUE", description: `sd`}})
    })
})
const client = new Client(config);
client.start();
```

Would mean a lot if you could help me find the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You may have added the intents to the `client` constant, but you are using `bot` constant which has no intents.

Comment: Yeah that was the one issue but I also found another way to do it. I've already fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I now realise that there are quite a few issues with the code you have provided.

### No. 1 - Client Definitions

It looks like you're defining three different clients. (`bot`, `client`, and possibly `Client`.)

You should organise your code in such a way that all events and commands are tied to one client object, as having multiple clients running can lead to rate-limiting and performance issues. (as well as being completely and utterly pointless.)

The error seems to be stating that `bot` is not given any intents during its creation, which could be fixed with the use of...

```js
// ...
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
// ...
```

### No. 2: Reference to an Undefined Variable

On the line where you define `client` at the start of the file, you use `new Client`, despite the fact that `Client` has not been imported yet, and is imported later in the file. This won't work, as `Client` is `undefined` at that point in the program.

### No. 3: Re-assignment of a constant

It also seems that you re-assign another `const client` near the end of your file. This will cause an error, as `client` is already a defined constant which cannot be over-written.

### No. 4: Access to Message Intents *(maybe???)*

As of recently, discord requires that you enable [Gateway Intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents) to be able to access certain events and data (such as Server Messages and Members).

To enable the intents, head to the [Discord Developer Dashboard](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your bot, select "Bot" from the sidebar, and enable the intents you need access to.

[image]

While this intent is not required to be able to read messages until April 30th, 2022, if your bot specifies the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent, this option needs to be enabled.

If your bot is in more than 100 servers, you will need to verify your bot to be able to continue accessing data which requires these intents. More about that [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412).

Comment: Hello! I've already fixed my problem. I changed clients and also added const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents });. It fixed all my problems. But, I don't know how to update package.json and package-lock.json it always sends build error when i updated discord.js is there a safe way to do it?